# php array selector unsure of differnce

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

hi I working with Drupal and it uses arrays to a level I'm not very familier with, I've a quick question which is what is the difference between these 'selectors'(is that the right term)?

This causes an error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in..."

```
$node['field_geoloc']
```

this works (im using it in an if != null statement)

```
$node->field_geoloc
```

hopefully an easy question...
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy.. the error says it all:

> "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in..."

You are attempting to use an object as an array.

Object properties aren't accessibly using the `$array['key']` method that you are used to. You need to access properties like:

```
`$object->property`
```

If you have an object, you can get the properties from that array by using the [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) method. But I know from experience that you should not use that method with a $node in Drupal.

Comment: am I right in thinking => is the opposite, to alter / insert a value into a object property.

Answer (score 2):

`->` is operator for accessing public object properties (and call public methods). In order for an object properties to be accessed with `$object['key']` syntax, it have to implement [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/ArrayAccess). Other option is to cast the object to array ( `$node = (array) $node` (but this will work only for first-level keys, e.g. it will turn `$node->page` to `$node['page']`, but not `$node->page->title` to `$node['page']['title']` - the later will be accessible via `$node['page']->title`

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't use object as an array.

That first is an array and that second is an object.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is an array, the second one is an object (of class StdClass).
But you may be interested in this interface: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php which allows accessing an object as an array (so you do $obj['key'] instead of $obj->key)